# How to set PyQt5 Qtimer to update in specified interval?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimer

I would like to update the Qtimer according to a framerate of 15 FPS - so my def update(): recieves a signal every 0,06 s. Can you help me? I have attached a code example below where my setInterval input is  1/15, but I dont know if that is the way to go. Thanks.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

def update():
    print('hey')

fps = 15
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.setInterval(1/fps)
timer.start()
```

Comment: Except for the interval computation (QTimer intervals are set in milliseconds, so it should be 1000/15), that's the correct approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the following errors:

- `setInterval()` receives the time in milliseconds, so you must change it to `timer.setInterval(1000/fps)`.
- Like many Qt components, the QTimer needs you to create QXApplication and start the event loop, in this case a QCoreApplication is enough.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore


def update():
    print("hey")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    fps = 15
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(update)
    timer.setInterval(1000 / fps)
    timer.start()

    app.exec_()
```