# How Python QTimer and graphical user interface (GUI) applications with Qt works together?

Tags: python, qtgui, qtimer

I started the timer and connect to function call “read_file” at interval 1sec. However, GUI interface does not come up. I do not understand on how Python QTimer and QT GUI work together? What can I do so my GUI page pop up and display the ping status. Any help I would appreciated.

```
import sys
from reachable_gui import *
import subprocess
import threading
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import os

def signal(self):
    
    self.Button_Manual.clicked.connect(Manual)
    self.Button_Pdf.clicked.connect(Pdf)
    read_file(self)
   
def Manual():
    pass

def Pdf():
    pass
      
def read_file(self):
        {
    #read line by line IP and device from a file and pass it to ping()
    }
  timer = QtCore.QTimer()
  timer.timeout.connect(self.read_file)
  timer.setInterval(1000)
  timer.start()
        
def ping(self,IP,name):
    { 
    # ping the device and update GUI status.
    }
    
Ui_MainWindow.ping = ping
Ui_MainWindow.signal = signal
Ui_MainWindow.Manual = Manual
Ui_MainWindow.Pdf = Pdf
Ui_MainWindow.read_file = read_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.signal()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you run `ui.signal()` which runs `app.exec_()` which normally runs untill you close main window - and it blocks next instructions so it should be executed as last command. But you run it before `MainWindow.show()` so it couldn't execute it to display window. You should use only one `app.exec_()` - at then end - and it should keep working both: window and timer.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing! Once, I remove the app.exe_() from signal() function then read_file() would not execute and all I get is default GUI page ( which I built in from QT). I need to update that page every 1sec. by reading from file and able to ping the device.

Comment: Just updated code so I can use Threading option. Now it does "read_file" and get the update GUI page once then it stop. no more update. How can I repeat the process for update status?

Comment: `threading.Timer` runs code only once and you would have to use `threading.Timer` again at the end of `read_file`. BUT maybe better use `QTimer` in `PyQt` which have `setInterval` - [How to set PyQt5 Qtimer to update in specified interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59094207/how-to-set-pyqt5-qtimer-to-update-in-specified-interval)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to correct the issue with redirect the signal function at the end of read_file.  Now I am getting "free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)" error. Not sure  on how to fix this one?

Comment: `free()` can means C/C++ function which frees memory. And maybe it has problem when you run `QTimer` in function which was started by `QTimer`. It creates recursion. But if you use `setInterval` then it shouldn't need to run `QTimer` at the end of `read_file` - `QTimer` should already run `read_timer` again and again using time in `setInterval`.

Comment: My apology, I did not update the code before. in this case it runs for for awhile then it gives me error " Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Comment: Better use `setInterval` instead of running `QTimer` again at the end of `read_file` because it is method created specially for running many times.

Comment: No joy. It seems work only in single shoot not in loop as I define 1sec. in my code. May be I am missing something? not sure.

Comment: meanwile I create simple example which use `QTimer to update `QLabel` using current time and it works all time. But I don't do this inside function but directly in `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps you resolve your problem but this is example how to use `QTimer` to run function many times.

But if function runs longer then it may create longer interval.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import datetime
#import time
   
def read_file():
    #time.sleep(2) # simulate long-running function
    
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M:%S')
    label.setText(current_time)
    
    print('current_time:', current_time)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    
    # some GUI in window
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel(window, text='???')
    window.setCentralWidget(label)
    window.show()
    
    # timer which repate function `read_file` every 1000ms
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(read_file)
    timer.setInterval(1000)
    timer.start()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```